# IIS is throwing an HTML page error saying "An asynchronous operation cannot be started ..."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, iis, async-await

I have found a couple examples of this error occurring in the forums but I don't apparently have the technical knowledge to make my case be truly 'async all the way' - if this is even the problem.

The error when caught is:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous
>   operations may only be started within an  asynchronous handler or
>   module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this
>   exception occurred while  executing a Page, ensure that the Page is
>   marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an 
>   attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported
>   within ASP.NET request processing. Instead,  the asynchronous method
>   should return a Task, and the caller should await it.
>
> at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Create() at
>   myCompany.System.Turhh.Turhh.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__1(Object
>   sender, GetInfoCompletedEventArgs e) at
>   myCompany.System.TurhhWebServices.InfoServiceClient.OnGetInfoCompleted(Object
>   state)

The code:

```
public void GetInfoAsync(GetInfoRq request, object Infotate)
{
    if ((this.onBeginGetInfoDelegate == null))
    {
        this.onBeginGetInfoDelegate = new BeginOperationDelegate(this.OnBeginGetInfo);
    }
    if ((this.onEndGetInfoDelegate == null))
    {
        this.onEndGetInfoDelegate = new EndOperationDelegate(this.OnEndGetInfo);
    }
    if ((this.onGetInfoCompletedDelegate == null))
    {
        this.onGetInfoCompletedDelegate = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnGetInfoCompleted);
    }
    base.InvokeAsync(this.onBeginGetInfoDelegate, new object[] {
                request}, this.onEndGetInfoDelegate, this.onGetInfoCompletedDelegate, Infotate);
}


private BeginOperationDelegate onBeginGetInfoDelegate;
private EndOperationDelegate onEndGetInfoDelegate;
private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback onGetInfoCompletedDelegate;

public event System.EventHandler<GetInfoCompletedEventArgs> GetInfoCompleted;

public System.IAsyncResult BeginGetInfo(GetInfoRq request, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
{
    return base.Channel.BeginGetInfo(request, callback, asyncState);
}

public GetInfoRs EndGetInfo(System.IAsyncResult result)
{
    return base.Channel.EndGetInfo(result);
}

private System.IAsyncResult OnBeginGetInfo(object[] inValues, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
{
    return this.BeginGetInfo(rq, callback, asyncState);
}

private object[] OnEndGetInfo(System.IAsyncResult result)
{
    GetInfoRs retVal = this.EndGetInfo(result);
    return new object[] {retVal};
}

private void OnGetInfoCompleted(object state)
{
    if ((this.GetInfoCompleted != null))
    {
        InvokeAsyncCompletedEventArgs e = ((InvokeAsyncCompletedEventArgs)(state));
        var ea = new GetInfoCompletedEventArgs(e.Results, e.Error, e.Cancelled, e.Infotate);
        try
        {
            // Note: Encapsulating this in a Task.Run() hides the issue on the server (here)
            // but IIS still dumps its HTML page with an await/async error info.
            this.GetInfoCompleted(this, ea);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            // HELP:
            // Most of the time, this works fine. About 1 in 10 times, this exception is thrown.
            // When this exception is thrown (and caught), IIS still dumps its HTML async/await error
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" **** AWAIT/ASYNC EXCEPTION 3 **** ");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code behind the GetInfoCompleted:

```
channel.GetInfoCompleted += new EventHandler<GetInfoCompletedEventArgs>(async (sender, e) =>
{
    await complete(); // complete contains an 'await Task.Run(async() => { some server work here });' job
});
```

This exception only occurs about 1 out of 10 times running locally. On production, it occurs almost every time. Essentially, on really fast servers, when the async calls happen synchronously rather than asynchronously, this throws the exception and irritates IIS causing it to dump the HTML error page down to the client. When these calls are made asynchronously, some time after IIS has gracefully given a good result to the client and the client moves on to its next task, everything is fine and this error-prone call on the server successfully accomplishes its mission (whether it is successful or not does not matter to the client - this is why it is threaded out as a post-operation task).

Comment: not full code for reproduce it. Did you get any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is a lot of old code, a lot of complexity over ten years. Outside of doing a complete overhaul, not sure what other options there are.